# .htaccess RewriteCond for existing and non-existing files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to **use .htaccess to redirect all url requests of a certain subpath ("URL/somefolders/main/..") to one basefile** named "_index.php". So I implemented the following .htaccess to the "folder" *URL/somefolders/main/* :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /main/_index.php?oldpath=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The redirection **works fine for all non-existant files**, but if the file **exists then it is called without redirection**. I suppose this is because I ordered to do so by the "!" in the RewriteCond, but all my tries to change it failed.

**How do I have to change the above code to redirect all files (existant or not) ?**

**Edit:**

All my tries still end up uneffective or erroneous.
The latter with the Apache log error:

`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Currently I fear that in fact I did correctly allow non-existant files in most of my before tries but get me a problem with an endless loop due to included files - is this possible? And if so can the .htaccess distinguish between "internal" and "external" file requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original rules are the most common implementation you'll see, where `REQUEST_FILENAME` is checked for existing files or directories to prevent things like CSS and images from being rewritten.  But that's not what you want.

So you correctly attempted to remove the `RewriteCond` directives but ended up with an infinite rewrite loop. That is likely because the subsequent `RewriteRule` is also attempting to rewrite `_index.php` back to itself.

You can fix that by adding a `RewriteCond` which specifically matches `_index.php` to prevent it from looping on itself.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
# Don't apply the rewrite to _index.php to prevent looping
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !main/_index\.php
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /main/_index.php?oldpath=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I'll also simplify the matched group in `RewriteRule`.  `([^?]*)` captures everything up to the first `?`, but the expression received by `RewriteRule` will never include the query string or `?` anyway. You may instead simply use `(.*)` to capture whatever is present.

```
RewriteRule (.*) /main/_index.php?oldpath=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I tried this and it had definitely a change in the kind of error (it is now a browser(?) redirection error instead of an internal 500). The difference probably is the endless loop of the _index.php - which I totally failed to realize. I think now I still suffer from endless loops of files which are included by the _index.php as I feared in the "Edit" of my OP. Will there be a good way out of it too? - the only way I can initially think of is to mask all includefiles by a different suffix, which would probably work but seems not a "nice" solution.

Comment: @Wooz Browsers may aggressively cache paths and redirects. Before anything else, I would recommend testing this in a different browser or in an incognito session.  And when you refer to files included by _index.php, how do you mean included? If by PHP includes, then Apache is not really involved. Any errors you see should be detailed in the Apache error log.

Comment: Another thank you to you, for saying "If by PHP includes, then Apache is not really involved." That brought me away from my fear of immanent endless loops due to the PHP includes (done by `include_once`) and so I was able to remember I included a `header('Location:..')` just about a good hour ago - ooops. I excluded this and now all seems fine

Comment: @Wooz So you're all sorted out then?

Comment: Well, I have some other stuff ahead such as a) finding out whether I could hide the redirect url "_index.php?old_path=xxx.php" from the user to make him feel like he is working under the url he entered and b) adjusting the paths of css's as the script now always runs in the context of the main path ... but as I haven't starting investigating this I though to better not bother anyone with this yet. But my posted problem is solved :-)

Comment: Since you are not using `[R]` I would not expect the browser to see the _index.php redirect URL. It may make a difference if you express it as `main/_index.php` instead of `/main/_index.php` (no leading /) ,and again be aware of the browser caching old redirects, making it difficult to debug.

Comment: Hmm after emptying all caches FF stopped showing the redirected URL and IE is showing my handmade 404 page on every call - that is a bit surprising, but at least this should be a problem in the PHP :-)